# How to read from multiple render textures and set texture 2d values Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, textures, texture2d, render-to-texture

So my idea is to create a real time security camera system on a texture in unity. The idea is to use multiple unity cameras scattered throughout a scene and have them all render to a RenderTexture. And then combine then onto 1 texture 2D which I could then either overlay the screen with or attach to an object in the scene. (most likely just overlay the screen with)

So my question then becomes how do I read from multiple RenderTextures in script in Unity? How can I then write blocks of the image to a texture2D in scipt as well to segments of the image?

This is what I am doing currently

```
public class Cameras : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RawImage outText;
    public RenderTexture[] cameras;
    public int imgWidth;
    public int imgHeight;

    void Start()
    {
        Texture2D[] textures = new Texture2D[cameras.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < cameras.length; ++i)
        {
            textures[i] = new Texture2D(cameras[i].width, cameras[i].height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        }
        Texture2D Combined = new Texture2D(imgWidth, imgHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < cameras.length; ++i)
        {
            //is this a decent way?
            RenderTexture.active = cameras[i];
            textures[i].ReadPixels (new Rect (0, 0, cameras[i].width, cameras[i].height), 0, 0);
            textures[i].Apply ();
            RenderTexture.active = null;
            Color32[] camPixels= textures[i].GetPixels32(0);
            /* someway to combine it?
            for(int i = camOffset; i < camBlock.width; ++i)
            {
                for(int j = camOffset; j < camBlock.height; ++j)
                {
                Combined.SetPixel(i,j,camPixels);
                }
            }
            */
        }
       
        outText.texture = Combined;
       
    }
}
```

As a follow up question, say I wanted to do some effects. How would I write solely to the red channel or the green channel of the Combined texture?

Thanks for the help in advance!